# How pointers work in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I have a quick question about how pointers work in Objective C.

In C we have:

```
int a = 1;
int *b;
b = &a;
//b is 1.
```

But in Objective C everything is already a pointer. So if we have:

```
NSString *a = @"String";
NSString *b;
b = a;         //I know this syntax is wrong but please bear with me.
```

will b equal "String"? Or will b point to a, which holds the value "String"?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Since Objective-C is a superset of C, any code that looks like C code should have the same behavior, and this included pointers.  That said, the compiler does inject retain/release operations around assignments to manage memory (ARC).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

B and A will both point to the same memory address which holds the actual String "String".

To clarify, if you compile and run this:

```
NSString *a = @"String";
NSString *b;
b = a;

NSLog(@"A is %@ %p",a,a);
NSLog(@"B is %@ %p",b,b);
```

The output is:

```
2015-03-26 21:35:09.860 ObjCTest[1379:187000] A is String 0x100b25068

2015-03-26 21:35:09.860 ObjCTest[1379:187000] B is String 0x100b25068
```

I literally ran this code now, and the output shows that both A and B point to the same NSString object - which is at memory location 0x100b25068, and contains the value "String".

Comment: But note that `&a` and `&b` are not the same. They are still two separate variables each at their own address. But both point to the same object on the heap.

Answer (score 3):

> In C we have:

```
int a = 1;
int *b;
b = &a;
//b is 1.
```

Actually, `*b == 1`. `b` is the memory address of `a` (which is what `&a` means).

> But in Objective C everything is already a pointer. So if we have:

```
NSString *a = @"String";
NSString *b;
b = a;         //I know this syntax is wrong but please bear with me.
```

> will b equal "String"? Or will b point to a, which holds the value "String"?

`b` and `a` point to the same `NSString` object, similar to how C works.